# Nil while unwrapping an Optional value Error

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uivisualeffectview, weak

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

With following Code:

```
weak var previewBlurView : UIVisualEffectView?

func blurPreviewWindow() {
    if (self.previewBlurView == nil) {
        var blurEffect: UIVisualEffect
        blurEffect = UIBlurEffect.init(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Dark)
        self.previewBlurView? = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
        self.previewView.addSubview(self.previewBlurView?)
        self.previewBlurView!.frame = self.previewView.bounds
    }

    self.previewBlurView?.alpha = 0.0
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0.0, options: [.BeginFromCurrentState, .CurveEaseOut], animations: {() -> Void in
        self.previewBlurView?.alpha = 1.0
    }, completion: { _ in })
}
```

I get the crash on the line:

```
self.previewView.addSubview(self.previewBlurView?)
```

**NOTE**

It turned out that all the views were nil due to an external problem of the view controller's instance not referring to the proper one.  So in this case, self.previewBlurView turned out to be nil.

Comment: `self.previewView` is `nil`

Comment: Even when I assign a different view that is not nil, I get the same error.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the `?` in the assignment of `self.previewBlurView`:

```
self.previewBlurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
```

What happens otherwise is that the assignment only happens when `self.previewBlurView` is actually non-`nil` in the beginning which it is not because you are in the process of assigning something to it.

Compare the following:

```
var a : Int? = 12
a? = 13
print(a)

var b : Int?
b? = 13
print(b)
```

Which prints

> Optional(13)
>   nil

The assignment `b?  = 13` only happens if `b` is not `nil` which it unfortunately is.

Comment: I am still getting the same error, even without it. If I don't do             self.view.addSubview(self.previewBlurView!) , I get an error.

Comment: self.view.addSubview(self.previewBlurView!) That line gives the error.  Saying "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value".  Even when I remove ? at the assignment, the same.

Comment: @gizmodo then please set a breakpoint on that line and inspect what the values are.

Comment: Somehow previewBlurView is nil when I check the values. weak var previewBlurView : UIVisualEffectView? Should that be changed?

Comment: @gizmodo ah yes, I overlooked that, remove the 'weak'

Comment: When weak is removed, it's no longer nil ; However, same error on the same line...